# How can i create a remote latch in java?

Tags: java, currency, executor, countdownlatch

At the moment I have a server that:

1) Launches 100 servlet requests using an executor on localhost

2) Executes the servlet requests.

3) Decrements a latch counting the total amount of completed servlets.

4) Calculates the execution time.

I would like to move point 1, 3 and 4 on another "client" machine.

So my client should send 100 requests to the server's servlet, wait for all responses (maybe using a remote latch?) and then calculate execution time.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and issue a `shutdown()` after supplying it with the 100 requests, won't the `workQueue` function as the latch? You can `awaitTermination()` to calculate the total execution time.

Comment: But the ThreadPoolExecutor is on the client and the 100 requests take place on the server... I think that awaitTermination() await until the last request has been submitted, not completed. Right?

Comment: Not if you await the response in your tasks' run() methods.